# How to build a custom documentation page without creating a paclet or using Wolfram Workbench?

Tags: documentation, workbench, paclets, resourcefunction

One of the new features about Wolfram Mathematica 13 that I am very excited about is the ability to create custom documentation.
I want to start documentation for the following areas:

- my own custom functions that as EntityValueAssociation mentioned in another location [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/261263/how-to-keep-track-of-multiple-properties-of-entities).
- Resource Functions in order to have a way to see the workings of the function when the Internet is not readily accessible (for example, while in a plane at 30,000 feet, or in a car, or in an area far away from population centers such as a natural park).
- and more!

I am wondering if Mathematica 13 includes a new simple way to create my own documentation for the two important scenarios above without opening Wolfram Workbench or reading through the source code.

I would also like to, however, know how to also create a paclet and what some good resources such as tutorials, community posts, videos, etc. going over how to build a paclet.

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/262931/what-are-the-best-resources-for-paclet-development/262964#262964